# What is the creationist view on animals equipped with lethal weapons?

Tags: creation

If God created the world with the intention that his creatures should live in harmony (as pictured in Isaiah 11:6-9) why did he create some animals with lethal weapons?

Why do spiders make webs to trap insects? Why do scorpions have venomous stings? Why do lions have teeth that are great for eating meat but lousy for eating grass?

Comment: Isaiah 11:6-9 is about the future, not this present earth.

Comment: True, but when God saw that his creation "was good", is it unreasonable to assume a similar harmony? Or do you think animals killed each other in the garden of Eden?

Comment: There are some theologians who believe that the fall of man turned the whole world into a hostile environment.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE! When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent).  I'm trying to ascertain whether this is a legitimate or rhetroical question.  We really are a Q&A site, not a forum - and this seems more like a discussion starter than a real request for information.

Comment: Affable Geek, I understand your concern. I can assure you that the question is not rhetorical. It really is something I've been thinking about, and I've posted it out of a sincere desire to find a (possible) answer. The title "What is the creationist view on..." is intended to signal this. I apologize if that is not clear.

Comment: I think this is a good question. I vote to leave it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is He didn't create animals with lethal weapons in the beginning.  In the beginning (Genesis 1) there was no death, thus no animal ate another.  "By man came death" through the entrance of sin. (1 Corinthians 15:21, Romans 6:23)  Therefore after sin animals began to devour one another.  A full 40 minute well done presentation on the creation and fall of man is found here- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQmLVU_nvo8

Hope that helps :)